Why am I receiving a 400 error with missing parameters when trying to retrieve JSON data from a specific XHR request?
I am trying to scrape JSON data from the XHR request named "articles" in the Network tab of the following website: Scilit Publications.
Here’s the code I’ve written:
import cloudscraper
import json

url = "https://www.scilit.net/api/solr/articles"

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

payload = {
    "bPublic": True,
    "pub_year": 2024,
    "language": "English",
    "type": "JOURNAL-ARTICLE"
}

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
response = scraper.post(url, params=headers)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.content)

try:
    json_data = response.json()
    file_path = "data.json"

    with open(file_path, "w") as json_file:
        json.dump(json_data, json_file, indent=4)
        print(f'JSON data successfully saved to {file_path}')

except ValueError:
    print('Response is not valid JSON.')
    json_data = response.text

else:
    print(f'Request failed with status code {response.status_code}')
    file_path = "json.data"

Problem:
When I run this code, I receive a 200 status code, but the response content is:
{"error":400,"error_msg":"Missing parameter"}

It also print:
JSON data successfully saved to data.json
Request failed with status code 200

It seems that the server is returning a 400 error stating that a parameter is missing, but I can’t figure out which parameter is missing. My goal is to retrieve the JSON data present in the "articles" file that I see in the XHR tab of the Network tab of the browser.
What I’ve Tried:

Ensured the headers match those used in the browser.

Confirmed that the payload includes the relevant parameters like pub_year, language, and type.

Used cloudscraper to bypass any potential anti-bot measures.


Question:
What might be causing this error, and how can I correctly retrieve the JSON data from the "articles" file in the XHR tab? Do I need to modify my headers or payload, or is there another approach I should take?

You have defined the payload dictionary, which contains the POST payload, but you haven't actually made it part of the request. You have attached the headers, but not the payload.

Where is the documentation for this API? Do you need to authenticate to use the API? Why are you using cloudscraper when this is an API call? It's not web-scraping

i try to open the url in my browser and get `404
Sorry, we can't find the page you are looking for`

sir you are right but as I add  payload in requests still it does not work

sir if you do not mind can you give me code which show  me how to effectively work with cloudscraper if we have not api and if we have api plz sir so in future i can easily handle them
